# Finder is reverting to root of network share for each folder deletion

Tags: finder, macos, sharing

I have a very odd error happening in one of our Macs.  We have a network share setup (afp), and whenever a user on a certain Mac deletes a folder on this share, the finder window drops all the way back to the root of the network share.  This is very frustrating, as file deletion takes place frequently on this share.  The problem has been replicated, and I have only been able to replicate it with folders, not files.  Also, the issue seems to cause the connection to the share to break occasionally, with a reboot being the only users recourse to reconnect (disconnecting and reconnecting to the share apparently doesn't work, but I have not seen the connection totally break personally).  As a workaround, this user creates a "trash" folder in every folder- dropping all of the files in this folder and then deleting it when they are done.  Any ideas what could be causing this?  We have several other Macs that are also running Osx 10.12.6, and are not experiencing this issue.

Comment: Does it exhibit this problem in SMB?  What type of file share is this?  A native Apple file server, a 3rd party server implementing AFP?

Comment: I have not tested SMB as it is not a viable solution for this case.  The share is an ubuntu server with EXP chassis implementing AFP as well as SMB.  I kind of ruled out the share as being an issue since we have 6 other similar macs that do not experience this issue.

Comment: So, it’s a Samba share.  What version of Samba are you using?

Comment: The command "smbstatus" returned the samba version of...                         Samba version 4.3.11-Ubuntu  We actually have a new solution in development, as this is an older system (Ubuntu 14.04).  I was just trying to get this issue resolved before we put the new system in production, since I do not like unresolved issues.